# Receive Payment BEFORE an Invoice has been created

Tags: payment, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to make a link on my website that allows a customer to pay us money for a task we will be working on for them.  I have looked through Intuit's/Quickbook's developer website and articles, and I have to say they are not much help.   Currently I'm not sure if I am going to have to create an app that uses some sort of web connector, of if I can just get a link from my account somewhere, or create a webpage that just connects to Quickbooks.
Has anyone here done this before, and if so is there any direction you could point me in? I've tried asking on their forums & support forms but have yet to receive any response.

Comment: This sounds like you're asking for us to recommend a tool or app, which this site is not appropriate for. If you're truly looking for software development help, then you should tell us what programming language you're developing in, what version of QuickBooks, show us what you've tried so far (e.g. post some code), etc.

Comment: I am using cakephp and QuickBooks Desktop, though I don't really know where to start.  I know I have to build an application and use web connect but I'm still stuck.  But like you said this isn't really the place to be asking for that type of help I guess.

Comment: Did you try a Google search for "quickbooks desktop php" at all? There's a whole lot of results that turn up for that search, many of them doing almost exactly what you're describing. At the very least, update your question with those details you provided -- CakePHP, QuickBooks desktop (but what year, version, edition, etc.?). How are you processing credit cards now? Are you processing credit cards now? Payment gateway?